# Erro ao exportar DataGridview para DataTable

Tags: c#, microsoft-excel

Estou tentando gerar uma planilha do Excel com base em uma DataTable, todos os dados estão no formato determinado, porém o formato de Data está no padrão americano ("MM/dd/YYYY"). Segue o código da função:

```
        //Metodo que exporta um grid para planilha exel
    public static void exportaExcelFormatado(DataGridView grid, String cabecalho, bool style = false, int retirarUltimasColunas = 0, DataTable dat = null, String rodape = "")
    {
        Log.Trace(logger, "exportaExcelFormatado");
        int linha = 2;

        int qtdeColunas = grid.Columns.Count - retirarUltimasColunas;

        try
        {
            if (grid.Rows.Count > 0)
            {

                SaveFileDialog salvar = new SaveFileDialog();// novo
                Excel.Application App; // Aplicação Excel
                Excel.Workbook pasta; // Pasta
                Excel.Worksheet planilha; // Planilha
                object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;


                // define algumas propriedades da caixa salvar
                salvar.Title = "Exportar para Excel";
                salvar.Filter = "Arquivo do Excel *.* | *.*";
                DialogResult resultado = salvar.ShowDialog(); // mostra

                if (resultado == DialogResult.OK)
                {

                    App = new Excel.Application();
                    pasta = App.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
                    planilha = (Excel.Worksheet)pasta.Worksheets.get_Item(1);



                    planilha.Cells[1, 1] = cabecalho;
                    planilha.Range["A1", GetColumnLetterByIndex(qtdeColunas) + "1"].Merge();
                    linha = 3;

                    for (int x = 1; x < qtdeColunas + 1; x++)
                    {
                        planilha.Cells[linha - 1, x] = grid.Columns[x - 1].HeaderText;
                    }

                    planilha.Range["A2", GetColumnLetterByIndex(qtdeColunas) + "1"].Font.Size = 10;
                    planilha.Range["A2", GetColumnLetterByIndex(qtdeColunas) + "1"].Font.Bold = true;
                    planilha.Range["A2", GetColumnLetterByIndex(qtdeColunas) + "1"].Font.Name = "Tahoma";

                    // passa as celulas do DataGridView para a Pasta do Excel
                    for (int i = 0; i <= grid.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j <= qtdeColunas - 1; j++)
                        {
                            DataGridViewCell cell = grid[j, i];
                            if (style)
                            {
                                if (cell.Style.BackColor.IsKnownColor == true)
                                    planilha.Cells[i + linha, j + 1].Interior.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(cell.Style.BackColor);
                                if (grid.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor.IsKnownColor == true)
                                    planilha.Cells[i + linha, j + 1].Interior.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(grid.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor);
                                if (cell.Style.ForeColor.IsKnownColor == true)
                                    planilha.Cells[i + linha, j + 1].Font.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(cell.Style.ForeColor);
                            }
                            DateTime data;
                            if (cell.ValueType.Name == "DateTime" || DateTime.TryParse(cell.Value.ToString(),out data))
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    Excel.Range rg = (Excel.Range)planilha.Cells[i + linha, j + 1];
                                    data = new DateTime();
                                    data = DateTime.Parse(cell.Value.ToString());
                                    if (data.Hour == 0 && data.Minute == 0 && data.Second == 0 && data.Millisecond == 0)
                                    {
                                        rg.EntireColumn.NumberFormatLocal = "dd/MM/aaaa";

                                            planilha.Cells[i + linha, j + 1] = data.Day.ToString("00") + "/" + data.Month.ToString("00") + "/" + data.Year.ToString("0000");

                                    }
                                    else
                                    {

                                        planilha.Cells[i + linha, j + 1] = data.ToString();

                                    }
                                }
                                catch
                                {
                                    planilha.Cells[i + linha, j + 1] = "";
                                }

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    if (cell.ValueType.Name == "String")
                                    {
                                        String valor = "";
                                        try
                                        {
                                            valor = cell.Value.ToString();
                                        }
                                        catch (Exception)
                                        {
                                            valor = "";
                                        }
                                        if (valor.Length > 50)
                                        {
                                            valor = valor.Substring(0, 50);
                                        }
                                        planilha.Cells[i + linha, j + 1] = valor;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        if (cell.ValueType.Name == "Nullable`1")
                                        {
                                            if (cell.Style.NullValue != "")
                                            {
                                                planilha.Cells[i + linha, j + 1] = cell.Style.NullValue.ToString();
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                planilha.Cells[i + linha, j + 1] = cell.EditedFormattedValue.ToString();
                                            }
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            try
                                            {
                                                planilha.Cells[i + linha, j + 1] = cell.Value.ToString();
                                            }
                                            catch (Exception)
                                            {
                                                planilha.Cells[i + linha, j + 1] = "";
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                catch (Exception)
                                {
                                    planilha.Cells[i + linha, j + 1] = cell.Value.ToString();

                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }

                    if (dat != null)
                    {
                        for (int lin = 0; lin < dat.Rows.Count; lin++)
                        {
                            for (int coluna = 0; coluna < dat.Columns.Count; coluna++)
                            {
                                if (dat.Rows[lin][coluna].GetType().UnderlyingSystemType.Name == "PictureBox")
                                {
                                    PictureBox box = (PictureBox)dat.Rows[lin][coluna];
                                    if (box != null)
                                    {
                                        planilha.Cells[grid.Rows.Count + 3 + lin, coluna + 2].Interior.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(box.BackColor);
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    planilha.Cells[grid.Rows.Count + 3 + lin, coluna + 2] = dat.Rows[lin][coluna];
                                    planilha.Cells[grid.Rows.Count + 3 + lin, coluna + 2].Font.Bold = true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    //Cabeçaho
                    planilha.Range["A1", GetColumnLetterByIndex(qtdeColunas) + "1"].Font.Size = 20;
                    planilha.Range["A1", GetColumnLetterByIndex(qtdeColunas) + "1"].Font.Name = "Tahoma";
                    planilha.Range["A1", GetColumnLetterByIndex(qtdeColunas) + "1"].HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;

                    //Corpo
                    planilha.Range["A3", GetColumnLetterByIndex(qtdeColunas) + grid.Rows.Count + 2].Font.Size = 8;
                    planilha.Range["A3", GetColumnLetterByIndex(qtdeColunas) + grid.Rows.Count + 2].Font.Name = "Tahoma";


                    //colunas
                    planilha.Range["A2", GetColumnLetterByIndex(qtdeColunas) + "2"].Font.Size = 10;
                    planilha.Range["A2", GetColumnLetterByIndex(qtdeColunas) + "2"].Font.Bold = true;
                    planilha.Range["A2", GetColumnLetterByIndex(qtdeColunas) + "2"].Font.Name = "Tahoma";

                    int cont = 0;
                    if (dat != null)
                    {
                        cont = dat.Rows.Count;
                    }

                    int linhaFinal = grid.Rows.Count + cont + 3;
                    planilha.Cells[linhaFinal, qtdeColunas] = "Relatório gerado em: " + DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString();

                    planilha.Range["A" + linhaFinal, GetColumnLetterByIndex(qtdeColunas) + linhaFinal].Font.Size = 7;
                    planilha.Range["A" + linhaFinal, GetColumnLetterByIndex(qtdeColunas) + linhaFinal].Font.Name = "Tahoma";
                    planilha.Range["A" + linhaFinal, GetColumnLetterByIndex(qtdeColunas) + linhaFinal].HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight;

                    if (rodape != "")
                    {
                        linhaFinal += 1;
                        planilha.Cells[linhaFinal, qtdeColunas] = rodape;
                        planilha.Range["A" + linhaFinal, GetColumnLetterByIndex(qtdeColunas) + linhaFinal].Merge();
                        planilha.Range["A" + linhaFinal, GetColumnLetterByIndex(qtdeColunas) + linhaFinal].Font.Size = 7;
                        planilha.Range["A" + linhaFinal, GetColumnLetterByIndex(qtdeColunas) + linhaFinal].Font.Name = "Tahoma";
                        planilha.Range["A" + linhaFinal, GetColumnLetterByIndex(qtdeColunas) + linhaFinal].HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight;
                    }

                    //ORIENTAÇÃO DE PÁGINA A4 E RETRATO
                    planilha.PageSetup.Orientation = Excel.XlPageOrientation.xlPortrait;
                    try
                    {
                        planilha.PageSetup.PaperSize = Excel.XlPaperSize.xlPaperA4;
                    }
                    catch (Exception erro1)
                    {

                    }

                    //Ajustando as colunas do excel
                    planilha.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit();

                    pasta.SaveAs(salvar.FileName, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue,
                    Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
                    pasta.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
                    App.Quit(); // encerra o excel

                    questions.confirmaExportacao();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                questions.erroExportação();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception erro)
        {
            Log.Erro(logger, "exportaExcelFormatado", erro.Message);
            questions.erroExportação();
        }

    }
```

O trecho responsável pela formatação dessa coluna:

```
                                DateTime data;
                            if (cell.ValueType.Name == "DateTime" || DateTime.TryParse(cell.Value.ToString(),out data))
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    Excel.Range rg = (Excel.Range)planilha.Cells[i + linha, j + 1];
                                    data = new DateTime();
                                    data = DateTime.Parse(cell.Value.ToString());
                                    if (data.Hour == 0 && data.Minute == 0 && data.Second == 0 && data.Millisecond == 0)
                                    {
                                        rg.EntireColumn.NumberFormatLocal = "dd/MM/aaaa";

                                            planilha.Cells[i + linha, j + 1] = data.Day.ToString("00") + "/" + data.Month.ToString("00") + "/" + data.Year.ToString("0000");

                                    }
                                    else
                                    {

                                        planilha.Cells[i + linha, j + 1] = data.ToString();

                                    }
                                }
                                catch
                                {
                                    planilha.Cells[i + linha, j + 1] = "";
                                }

                            }
```

UPDATE:

Da forma a seguir consigo deixar a data no formato certo, porém o ano aparece como "aaaa" no excel.

```
if (cell.ValueType.Name == "DateTime" || IsDate(cell.Value.ToString()))
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    Excel.Range rg = (Excel.Range)planilha.Cells[i + linha, j + 1];
                                    DateTime data = DateTime.Parse(cell.Value.ToString());
                                    if (data.Hour == 0 && data.Minute == 0 && data.Second == 0 && data.Millisecond == 0)
                                    {
                                        rg.EntireColumn.NumberFormatLocal = "dd/MM/aaaa";
                                        //DateTime x = data.Day.ToString("00") + "/" + data.Month.ToString("00") + "/" + data.Year.ToString("0000");
                                        String x = String.Format("{0:dd/MM/aaaa}", data);
                                        planilha.Cells[i + linha, j + 1] = x;
                                       // planilha.Cells[i + linha, j + 1] = data.Day.ToString("00") + "/" + data.Month.ToString("00") + "/" + data.Year.ToString("0000");

                                    }
                                    else
                                    {

                                        planilha.Cells[i + linha, j + 1] = data.TimeOfDay.ToString();
                                    }
                                }
                                catch
                                {
                                    planilha.Cells[i + linha, j + 1] = "";
                                }

                            }
```

Comment: Esta ocorrendo algum erro ou você deseja alterar o formato da data ?

Comment: Só gostaria de entregar a data como: "dd/MM/yyyy" de resto está tudo normal. Aliás, para alguns casos a data vem do formato correto.

Comment: Nó código do enunciado no  trecho responsável pela formatação o  NumberFormatLocal  está definido como  "dd/MM/aaaa" você chegou a alterar o para "dd/MM/yyyy" ?

Comment: Eu tentei de ambas as formas, mas sem sucesso. Esqueci de mencionar que qualquer dia depois do dia 12 ele faz corretamente, dias anteriores ele trata como mês.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui Resolver, bastava utilizar a seguinte linha:

```
planilha.Cells[i + linha, j + 1] = String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", data);
```